# Disable all splash graphics/texts on startup and shutdown?

Tags: lubuntu, plymouth

I have LUbuntu running on a special device which runs a single program on startup and ever. I only need the user to see the splash of my program. BIOS has been taken care of. Now for the rest. What do I need to do?

I found this suggestion:
`sudo mv /etc/init/plymouth-splash.conf /etc/init/plymouth-splash.conf.disabled`
But all it did was show nothing until I press something and LUbuntu shuts down...

Comment: Just remove `splash` from the kernel command line, but keep `quiet`.

Comment: How do you remove `splash`? `sudo apt-get remove splash` doesnt do it. And whats `quiet` for and what does it do?

Comment: See the linked post. You'll be told to remove `splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. The value is usually `quiet splash`, so you want to keep `quiet`, but remove `splash`.

Comment: It seems to replace the splash with log messages. I don't want to display the log messages either.

Comment: did you remove `quiet`?

Comment: Tried both ways. No difference.

Comment: Despite me repeatedly saying, keep `quiet`, remove `splash`?

Comment: Check my quickly edited comment. I tried both ways. First tried keeping quiet, but log messages kept showing, so I tried removing that too with no difference. I then added quiet back in, but again I still see messages when booting.

Comment: With the same volume of messages? Some messages are displayed even with `quiet` because they're logged with a higher level of importance. Try adding `loglevel=1` after `quiet` (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot)

Comment: That doesn't do anything either...